Computing the expected minimum of two sums of two independent Exponential variables
Given some independent and identically-distributed random variables $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2 \sim \text{Exp}(\mu)$, I'm trying to compute
$$
E[\min{(X_1 + X_2, Y_1 + Y_2)}]
$$
in order to model the expected first finishing time of two jobs that each contain two parts.
I've heard of the Gamma distribution and the Erlang distribution, but I have never formally learned about those. Instead, I've been trying to attack this problem from the perspective of Poisson processes. Specifically, my idea was to treat $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2$ as the times between events in some Poisson process with rate $\mu$ (because the times between events in Poisson processes are exponentially-distributed). This way, $X_1 + X_2$ would represent the time of occurrence of the second event in some Poisson process with rate $\mu$, and vice versa for $Y_1 + Y_2$. It would then just remain to figure out the expectation of the minimum from there, which I believe is easier to do. However, I have not been able to do this.
Can someone provide hints or a solution to this question?

 From simulation, I believe that the answer is $\dfrac{1.25}{\mu}$, but I have no idea why.


The sum of two exponentials is a $\Gamma(2,\mu)$. So the question is equivalent to asking what is $E(\min(Z_{1},Z_{2}))$ where $Z_{i}$ are iid $\Gamma(2,\mu)$ distributed.
See that for $x>0$, $P(\min(Z_{1},Z_{2})>x)=P(Z_{1}>x,Z_{2}>x)=P(Z_{1}>x)^{2}$
But $P(Z_{1}>x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}\mu^{2}te^{-\mu t}\,dt=\mu xe^{-\mu x}+e^{-\mu x}$
As for a positive random variable $X$, $E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X>t)\,dt$, you have
$$E(\min(Z_{1},Z_{2}))=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2\mu x}(\mu x+1)^{2}\,dx$$
You'll get precisely $$\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-2\mu x}x^{2}\mu^{2}\,+2x\mu e^{-2\mu x}+e^{-2\mu x})\,dx=\frac{1}{4\mu}+\frac{1}{2\mu}+\frac{1}{2\mu}=\frac{1.25}{\mu}$$
Alternatively, from the expression for $P(\min(Z_{1},Z_{2})>x)=e^{-2\mu x}(\mu x+1)^{2}$, you can differentiate and obtain the density and then compute the expectation.
